# Android - Trouble finding FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-arrayadapter, firebaseui

Been working on a few projos to become better familiar with Firebase and its awesomeness. Been wading through fine except I couldn't seem to find `FirebaseListAdapter<>` or `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<>`.

My Gradle (in Android Studio) file is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So I'm at a loss as to why I can't actually use/find those classes. Can anyone tell me where it is I am going wrong? I understand the majority of this stuff, even though it seems like Firebase has made some changes and what not.

Thank you very much and I am GREATLY appreciative to all help. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, this is my first post on Stack-O, sorry for my informality, will do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `firebase-ui-database` to get access to the database adapters:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
```